# I get warnings in eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

When I run my test in Eclipse I get a lot of warnings in red in console although it doesn't stop my execution and with chrome doesnt show any warnings. I wonder if I can get rid of them. I paste below the warnings that come up in console in red.

```
1502813688437   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1502813688445   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:37427
1502813688743   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin with args ["-marionette"]
1502813691158   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62402
1502813691575   Marionette  DEBUG   loaded listener.js
2017-08-15 17:14:51.696 plugin-container[1907:206445] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x913b, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-08-15 17:14:51.700 plugin-container[1907:206445] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x9503, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
Aug 15, 2017 5:14:51 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1502813691752   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for "about:blank"
1502813691853   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pagehide" for "about:blank"
1502813691853   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "unload" for "about:blank"
1502813691864   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "DOMContentLoaded" for "http://10.32.16.35:3000/"
1502813691904   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pageshow" for "http://10.32.16.35:3000/"
```

Comment: Have you done any research regarding this?

Comment: It sounds like you may not be familiar with the terms *standard output* and *standard error*, which are important here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output in red is what is written to `System.err` somewhere in the program (as opposed to `System.out`.  In the default configuration they both end up in the same place, hence the different coloring).  This is not necessary a bad thing, depending on what it indicates.

The only way to get rid of it is to either remove the offending lines from your program or avoid triggering them.  You can also redirect the System.err output to somewhere you do not see.